# How can I set WideBackgroundImage in App Manifest File for WP7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm following the directions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and am able to set the new WP8 tile info from a WP7 app using reflection so that if a user is on WP8, the wide tile is set and not set on WP7 since it isn't supported there.  Is there a way to set the WideBackGroundImage property in the WMAppManifest.xml file without upgrading the project to WP8 only?  This would be nice because it would be set whether the app has launched or not. The method linked above requires the app to run first before a user can expand the tile.

Comment: Have you tried editing the xml file manually?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot Yeah the app won't run because the manifest file fails schema validation because it doesn't know what to do with the <TemplateFlip /> tag.  Wondering if there is some undocumented way to add WP8 manifest features inside the AppExtra tag or something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is probably what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: This is what I linked to in my question.